# Not able to login google admin account after disabling SSO vai SAML

Tags: single-sign-on, google-apps, saml, saml-2.0

I first enabled SSO in my google domain and tried logging in with SAML.
It worked fine after fixing timezone issue.
Then I disabled the SSO by logging in the super admin account, we have two super admins in our domain.
Now with mail.domain.com I am able to log in all accounts in the domain, except the super admin domain.
That super admin link is redirected to SAML authentication Link (which is now removed and disabled) and not able to log in.

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Super Admins are not subject to SSO sign in. They automatically bypass it when you try to sign in. Because of this, you will need to use the Google Apps credentials to authenticate to your Super Admin account from mail.google.com.

More information about this can be seen [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60224) under 'How does SSO impact super administrators?'.